# LinkedIn Share Article removed custom parameters on Android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I'm trying to create a link that will share a website with UTM parameters and referral code from a website. I was able to use https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=%s&title=%s&summary=%s and they are successful in Desktop and IOS but on Android, it strips all the parameters. It's working on Desktop and IOS on the same link shared so it shouldn't be something on the link...
It's a simple a tag with href.
I know that this link is deprecated and I should use https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=%s but I tried it and it's not working on mobile. I'm stuck here for more that 2 weeks now. Please help!

I created this codepen https://codepen.io/Janasana/pen/zYdRjjw
`<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/release_notes%3Futm_campaign%3Dtesting%26utm_medium%3Dwebsite%26utm_source%3DLinkedin%26utm_content%3Dli-artikel-san-ri-val%26referral%3D34555" target="_blank">Test 2 Linked In</a>` and a video of the issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ge0tvBTlj7M. Basically I cannot see my utm parameters and referral upon sharing on Android LinkedIn app.

Comment: Do you have any code to share? Do you have an actual question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @dominicoder, I have prepared this codepen. It does exactly what I was referring to. Just keep it mind that I don't own the developers.google.com obviously. The issue is I have utm parameters on the link but it's not passing to linkedIn Android but is working on Desktop and IOS. https://codepen.io/Janasana/pen/zYdRjjw

Comment: You need to explain what "it's not passing to LinkedIn Android" means. I followed your link and can see the full URL in Firefox on my Android device. So I still don't understand what you are asking or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @dominicoder, in the codepen I have this link https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/release_notes?utm_campaign=testing&utm_medium=website&utm_source=Linkedin&utm_content=li-artikel-san-ri-val&referral=34555, I have tried this one on Android chrome browser and upon posting in LinkedIn app, I open the link I shared on linkedIn app and open it on Chrome browser. I am missing ?utm_campaign=testing&utm_medium=website&utm_source=Linkedin&utm_content=li-artikel-san-ri-val&referral=34555 on the link. Just tried on Android Firefox, same issue

Comment: What is "upon posting in LinkedIn app"? Can you share a video or something? I genuinely have no clue what you're describing.

Comment: @dominicoder, sorry for being unclear. Please see this video. Sorry no idea where should we upload video or attach here so I just put it on youtube. My issue is that my utm parameters are not on the link anymore. Thank you for your promptly reply https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ge0tvBTlj7M

Comment: Looks to me like an issue with the LinkedIn App. You'd have to ask someone that works on it, or file a bug with them or somthing.

Comment: @dominicoder, thank you so much for your response. I'll try to ask on LinkedIn.